# nvcc undefined reference to user defined function but works with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, cuda, nvcc

I am trying to teach myself CUDA and I wrote a very simple code (shown below). The code compiles fine with nvcc but the linker throws "undefined reference to" error to user defined functions. The code has 3 files: main.c , device.cu and device.h.

**main.c**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "device.h"

int main() {
   int nDevices;
   // Get the number of available devices
   getDevices(&nDevices);
   printf("Found %d devices\n", nDevices);
   return 0;
}
```

**device.h**:

```
#ifndef DEFINE_H
#define DEFINE_H
void getDevices(int *nDevices);
#endif
```

**device.cu**:

```
#include<cuda.h>
#include "device.h"
void getDevices(int *nDevices) {
   *nDevices = 0;
   cudaDeviceReset();
   cudaGetDeviceCount(nDevices);
}
```

I compile as

```
nvcc -c main.c
nvcc -c device.cu
```

These commands execute without any problem but when I link

```
nvcc -o main main.o device.o
```

I get

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `getDevices'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I then commented out lines 1, 5, and 6 in device.cu and renamed it as device.c. When I compiled and linked it with gcc, it works fine. Looks like I am making a very silly mistake but I cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: Try `nvcc -o main main.c device.cu`.

Comment: I get the same linker error

Comment: Found the problem! If I rename the main.c file as main.cu, it works without any issue. Oh wow that was very subtle.

Comment: The core problem is that when you pass code as a `.cu` file, nvcc uses a C++ host compiler, which implies functions in that file have C++ linkage with symbol mangling, rather than C linkage. See the linked duplicate for more details and workarounds